# Why doesn't my console.log message show when I press Start?

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I'm learning to use event listeners, I wanted to log pressing the "Start" button to the console to make sure the button works but I'm not getting any results when I test the `.html` file in devtools.

- I've verified the `index.js` name referenced in the `.html` file is the same
- I've tried the source code in the header
- I've added the `src=index.js` jQuery library through Google to the bottom before  `</body>`
- I've copied the code to *repl.it* to try a different environment

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function startQuiz() {
    $('#startButton').click(function(event){
        console.log("Keep Going");
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Herbal Medicine: Adaptogens</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="questions" href="store.html">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Intro to Herbal Adaptogens explaining what they are</p>
        <button id="startButton">Start</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the to see "Keep Going" in the console when I press "start" but instead nothing happens at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO @bethany. It is not firing because you are not triggering `startQuiz()`. Moving your listener out of that function will fix it.

Comment: Thanks Mike! It has been so very helpful cheers

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @bethany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the JQuery `click()` function inside the `startQuiz()` function. So it won't work unless the outer function (`startQuiz()`) is run first. You should put it inside a ready function so that it loads once the page is 'ready'.

Change your javascript to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startButton').click(function(event) {
        console.log("Keep Going");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Bethany no problem. You are also right by running `startQuiz()` first. Just thought I'd show you some common practice with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it inside a Jquery click function. This way it will fire when the document loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startButton').click(function(event) {
        console.log("Keep Going");
    }
});
```

Comment: Great thank you!
I was looking at some course materials after you reminded me about .ready and found out that calling the startQuiz function at the end of the document works as well:
function startQuiz() {
    $('#startButton').click(function(event){
        console.log("Keep Going");
    }
    );
}

($(startQuiz))

Answer (score 0):

No need to go with jQuery , you can just use js events.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Log Window</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  function logMe() {console.log('clicked');}
  </script>
  <button onclick="logMe()">logMe</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using inline event listeners is a bad practice... and he don't *need* jQuery, but he *can use* jQuery here.